# .NET RegEx to validate password between 6 and 20 characters with at least one upper case letter, one lower case letter and one digit

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex to validate passwords with the following specs:

It must be between 6 and 20 characters with at least one upper case letter, one lower case letter and one digit

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you add anything to this question to make it read less like a "do my work for me" request?

Comment: it's unlikly people will do your homework

Comment: Actually it's very likely, but you'll pay the price in reputation.

Comment: I don't understand why people get so bent out of shape when someone requests help writing a regular expression.  It's a valid question perfectly acceptable for StackOverflow.  Either help, or don't.

Comment: @Steve: well, since you asked, it bothers me because a) it's a common human response to be annoyed by someone asking for help, but unwilling to help themselves, and b) the tone makes it clear to me that the OP will use the answer, but not attempt to understand it, and his software (which I might use someday) will be the worse for it.

Comment: OK, you may be right.  And you're definitely entitled to your opinion.  I still have my "either help or don't" philosophy from my former forum moderator days.  It's a way of avoiding hostility inside specific topics.  But I'm not a moderator here and I understand that not everyone agrees with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this works:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]).{6,20}$
```

Here it is with [test cases in Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=9294def7-c51b-4480-939f-c716dc2778f5).

The idea is to use positive lookaheads to ensure that at least one lower case letter, one upper case letter, and one digit are contained within the password.  And then as a last step I simply specify a dot to allow any characters in the 6-20 character range.

Comment: That does not work.  That will pass values of 100 or more characters.

Comment: Will that match a string like "a1A===="?  That would seem to meet Jangwenyi's criteria.

Comment: Don't forget ^ and $ or it will match unlimited password length: ^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]{6,20}$

Comment: John, did you test it?  I don't get what you mean.  It doesn't allow a 21 character password if that's what you're getting at.  The {6,20} part prevents that.

Comment: Good, but this doesn't prevent other characters from breaking the length limit. Also, strictly speaking Jangwenyi didn't say that only [a-zA-Z0-9]{6} were required. So %%%Aa1 should be allowed and ABCDEabcde1234512345%%%%%%%%% should be forbidden, but your regex does the opposite.

Comment: @Steve, no it doesn't you don't have anchors.  Also, you aren't allowing other characters than alpha numeric.

Comment: Jim, good point I just fixed that.  Darin, also a good point, I've added the ^ and $.  Beta, I think this latest version solves that.

Comment: Yes, I think that does the trick. (Personally I make my edits explicit in a case like this.)

Comment: John - just one edit I think.  You know, I don't completely disagree with your method.  It's just that there are times when a single regex is preferred for brevity.  There are other times when a solution such as yours may be needed to handle extreme complexity.

Comment: No, yeah, I understand that regexps are powerful, but there are often so many pitfalls and unforeseen issues that they end up being overly complicated and unreliable.

Answer (score 4):

<s>Regexes are used for searching, not for validation.</s>  You should not strive to do this in a single regex.

That being said, since you are looking for character classes, and since regexes support them very well, I would suggest using two or three regexes, checking for a match of each one.

```
    bool IsPasswordValid(string password)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password) ||
            password.Length > 20 ||
            password.Length < 6)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if(!Regex.IsMatch(password, "\d") ||
            !Regex.IsMatch(password, "[a-z]") ||
            !Regex.IsMatch(password, "[A-Z]"))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

This is WAY more efficient than trying to encode all of the possible combinations in an overly complicated Regex.

Comment: Regexes are used all the time for validation.

Comment: Agreed, but that is not what they are made for.  The regex to FIND all valid IP addresses is WAY simpler and more efficient than the regex to VALIDATE an IP address.  Regexes are a search tool.  Useful for validation, yes, but not made for it.

Comment: -1: Searching a pattern it's a validation type; while this regex can ends complicated, I think this is a valid approach

Comment: I get your point.  But I don't think this task is too complicated for a single regex.

Comment: I agree and this is much easier to read and maintain.  Think about someone trying to maintain the other regexes posted.

Comment: It is completely incorrect to say that regular expressions are not used for validation. *Regular expressions* were *invented* as a way to concisely characterize membership rules for *regular languages*. The regular languages are those languages whose members can be *decided*, ie, verified, by a finite state machine.  That regular expressions can be used for search came later in the history of the study of regular languages. If this subject interests you, I started (but never completed) a series of articles on it: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/Regular+Expressions/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This allows spaces and special characters, but should follow your specs:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{6,20}$
```

I use [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) to help test my .Net regular expressions.