# length property in javascript not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

i want to restrict the user to enter the password in the range of 6-20 characters. but the function below in not working properly.

```
 function validatePass(pwd1, pwd2)
 {
var len = document.getElementById('pwd1').value;
if(len.length < 6 || len.length > 20)
{ pwd1.setCustomValidity('Enter 6-20 characters');
}
else if (pwd1.value != pwd2.value || pwd1.value == '' || pwd2.value == '' )
{
        pwd2.setCustomValidity('Password incorrect');
  } 
else 
{
    pwd2.setCustomValidity('');
}
}
```

the html code is:

```
<h4>Password</h4></td>
<td><input type="password" name="pwd1" size="30" id="pwd1" required placeholder="Enter 6-20 characters"></td></tr>
<tr><td>
<h4>Confirm Password</h4></td>
<td><input type="password" name="pwd2" id="pwd2" size="30" required onfocus="validatePass(document.getElementById('pwd1'), this);" oninput="validatePass(document.getElementById('pwd1'), this);">
</td></tr>
```

Comment: Why do you send `pwd1` if you don't use it? and what doesn't work properly? what happens?

Comment: Kinda weird `pwd1.value != pwd2.value || pwd1.value == '' || pwd2.value == ''` cuz if pwd1 and pwd2 may not be equal, why check both if empty?

Comment: @Bondye, the only thing that bothered you with this code...?

Comment: @gdoron No, not the only thing.... It is just a comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML5, you can use [pattern](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090825/forms.html#attr-input-pattern) attribute:

```
<input type="password" pattern=".{6,20}" name="pwd1" size="30" id="pwd1" required placeholder="Enter 6-20 characters"></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using regular expressions like this:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]).{6,20}$
```

Source: [.NET RegEx to validate password between 6 and 20 characters with at least one upper case letter, one lower case letter and one digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573313/net-regex-to-validate-password-between-6-and-20-characters-with-at-least-one-up)

Here is a full example:

```
function CheckPassword(inputtxt) 
{ 
var passw = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,20}$/;
if(inputtxt.value.match(passw)) 
{ 
alert('Correct, try another...')
return true;
}
else
{ 
alert('Wrong...!')
return false;
}
}
```

Source: http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/password-validation.php